# Turntables in Appliances and Standing Waves

Tags: thermodynamics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, conductors

I am just confused on a concept - maybe someone could correct me if I am wrong? I was just wondering why do some appliances contain a turntable.

Answer (score 1):

Microwave ovens use a magnetron that produces the microwaves, that inside the oven create *standing waves*. Because of this, there exists points of constructive and destructive interference. So this means there will be hot regions and cooler regions inside the oven.

What the turntable does then is allow whatever is being cooked to rotate so that the whole thing gets uniformly exposed to the hot spots in the microwave. If the turntable was not there, you'd find that there are parts that have been cooked or overcooked, and parts that are barely cooked at all.

However, in the absence of a turntable, some microwaves use fans that scatter the microwaves in many directions to disturb the hot and cold regions, to reduce possible uneven cooking.

Comment: Okay thanks! :)

Comment: No worries then. Cheers.